# every $\omega$-limit set is non wandering.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $f : R^n\mapsto R^n$, and solutions
for every initial value problem $x'=f(x)$, $x(0)=x_0$
exist for all $t\in R$ and are unique.
Write $\Phi_t(x_0)$ for the solution at time $t$.

Prove that every point in every $\omega$-limit set is non wandering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove that $\omega(x_0)$ is non wondering for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Fact:

- $\forall x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, its $\omega$-limit set $\omega(x_0)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n;\exists \{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}},~\text{such that}~t_n\to +\infty~\text{as}~n\to+\infty, \text{and}~\Phi_{t_n}(x_0)\to y \}$.

Now, $\forall x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\forall y\in\omega(x_0)$ and $\forall \epsilon>0, T>0$, we choose $\{t_n\}$ with $t_n\to +\infty$ satisfying $\Phi_{t_n}(x_0)\to y$.
With $B(y,\epsilon)$ open, there $\exists N_1>0$, such that $\Phi_{t_n}(x_0)\in B(y,\epsilon)$ for all $n>N_1$.
Choose $t_m, t_n$ such that $t_m, t_n>N_1$ and $t_m-t_n>T$.
Then $\Phi_{t_n}(x_0), \Phi_{t_m}(x_0)\in B(y,\epsilon)$, and $\Phi_{t_m}(x_0)=\Phi_{t_m-t_n}\Phi_{t_n}(x_0)\in \Phi_{t_m-t_n}B(y,\epsilon)$.
That is, $\Phi_{t_m}(x_0)\in\Phi_{t_m-t_n}B(y,\epsilon)\cap B(y,\epsilon)\neq\emptyset$ and $t_m-t_n>T$.

Answer (score 0):

Definition: A point $q\in Rn$ is called a non wandering point of the system
is defined by
$x'=f(x)$ if for every $\epsilon >0$ and every  $T>0$ there
exists some $t>T$ such that  the intersection of the ball $B(q,\epsilon)$
with its image $\Phi_t(B(q,\epsilon))$ is nonempty.
This definition that I use to start the proof.

Comment: Every $\omega$-set is referred to $\{\Omega(x);x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, or $\{\Omega(A);A\subset \mathbb{R}^n,~\text{with some further properties}\}$?

Comment: yes I write in the following.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. You want to prove something for all omega-limit set. omega limit set can be defined for a point or a subset: $\omega(A)=\cap_{t>0}\cup_{s>t}\Phi_s(A)$. $A$ can be a single point. I want to know you want to prove something for the omega-limit set for every single point, or a omega-limit set for every  subsets? @Layan

Answer (score 0):

yes, A point $x \in M$ is called nonwandering if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is a sequence of positive times $t_n \to \infty$ such that $\Phi t_n(U) \bigcap U\neq \phi$ for all $t_n$. The set of nonwandering points is denoted by $\Omega (f)$.
(i) $\Omega (f)$ is a closed invariant set.
(ii) $\Omega (f)$ contains all periodic orbits (including all fixed points).
(iii) $\omega_{+} (f)\subseteq \Omega (f)$  for all $x \in M.$

$\Omega (f)$ for the system $f (x, y) = (y, −x)$.